# Why is there no universal base class in C++?

Tags: c++, language-design, base-class

From a design point of view, why is that, in C++, there is no mother-of-all base-class, what's usually `object` in other languages?

Comment: This is really more of a philosophical question than a design question. The short answer is "because Bjarne apparently didn't want to do that."

Comment: Personally I think it is a design flaw to have everything derived from the same base class. It promtes a style of programming that causes more problems than it is worth (as you tend to have generic containers of object that you then need to case up from to use the actual object (This I frown apoun as bad design IMHO)). Do I really want a container that can house both cars and command automation objects?

Comment: @Martin but look at it this way: for example, up until C++0x auto, you had to use mile-long type definitions for iterators, or one-time `typedef`s. With a more generic class hierarchy, you could just use `object` or `iterator`.

Comment: @Santiago:  The use of a unified type system almost always means that you end up with a lot of code that relies on polymorphism, dynamic dispatch, and RTTI, all of which are relatively expensive and all of which inhibit optimizations that are possible when they are not used.

Comment: @GWW - ...other than the fact that it won't apply to any of the STL containers.

Comment: @Santiago There'd be no difference there with just using `void*`, then. Sure, you wouldn't have to mess around with really long type names, but then you'd also lose any semblance of a coherent interface for that iterator. As it is now, the iterator knows what kind of things it is pointing to, so `*it` will actually return a variable of the proper type. That'd be impossible if you'd typed that iterator as `void*` or `object`.

Comment: @Santiago Lezica: Or you could go with what the designers of the STL did and templatize the algorithms.

Answer (score 119, accepted):

The definitive ruling is found in [Stroustrup's FAQs](http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#object).
In short, it doesn't convey any semantic meaning. It will have a cost. Templates are more useful for containers.

> ### Why doesn't C++ have a universal class Object?
>
> - We don't need one: generic programming provides statically type safe alternatives in most cases. Other cases are handled using multiple inheritance.
> - There is no useful universal class: a truly universal carries no semantics of its own.
> - A "universal" class encourages sloppy thinking about types and interfaces and leads to excess run-time checking.
> - Using a universal base class implies cost: Objects must be heap-allocated to be polymorphic; that implies memory and access cost. Heap objects don't naturally support copy semantics. Heap objects don't support simple scoped behavior (which complicates resource management). A universal base class encourages use of dynamic_cast and other run-time checking.

Comment: We don't need no / base class object / we don't need no / thought control... ;)

Comment: @Piskvor - LOL I want to see the music video!

Comment: `Objects must be heap-allocated to be polymorphic` - I don't think this statement is generally correct. You can definitely create an instance of a polymorphic class on the stack and pass it on as a pointer to one of its base classes, yielding polymorphic behavior.

Comment: @Byron After reading your comment I agree completely. I have posted a question on this topic. (see linked in the right pane).

Comment: In Java, attempting to cast a reference-to-`Foo` into a reference-to-`Bar` when `Bar` does not inherit `Foo`, *deterministically* throws an exception.  In C++, attempting to cast a pointer-to-Foo into a pointer-to-Bar could send a robot back in time to kill Sarah Connor.

Comment: @supercat That's why we use dynamic_cast<>. To avoid SkyNet and mysteriously appearing Chesterfield sofas.

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe: Is there any built-in way to have a function accept and store pointers to arbitrary polymorphic objects (e.g. so that it can later pass them on to other functions which will either use or ignore them based on type) but have it reject non-polymorphic types?

Comment: @supercat You can at compile-time detect if they are polymorphic, yes. This means you can create a (template) function that can use them as arguments and reject non-polymorphic types. The template will use the exact type in it's default state. This is accomplished by SFINAE techniques, i.e. std::enable_if and std::is_polymorphic.  This sounds like a good SO question if my comment left you unsatisfied.

Comment: The "we don't need..." and "C++" can not be written on the same page. I am fixing a C++ code which rendered its own OOP hierarchy unusable with annotations

Answer (score 45):

Let's first think about why you'd want to have a base-class in the first place. I can think of a few different reasons:

1. To support generic operations or collections that will work on objects of any type.
2. To include various procedures which are common to all objects (such as memory management).
3. Everything is an object (no primitives!). Some languages (like Objective-C) don't have this, which makes things pretty messy.

These are the two good reasons that languages of the Smalltalk, Ruby and Objective-C brand have base-classes (technically, Objective-C doesn't really have a base-class, but for all intents and purposes, it does).

For #1, the need for a base-class that unifies all objects under a single interface is obviated by the inclusion of templates in C++. For instance:

```
void somethingGeneric(Base);

Derived object;
somethingGeneric(object);
```

is unnecessary, when you can maintain type integrity all the way through by means of parametric polymorphism!

```
template <class T>
void somethingGeneric(T);

Derived object;
somethingGeneric(object);
```

For #2, whereas in Objective-C, memory management procedures are part of a class's implementation, and are inherited from the base class, memory management in C++ is performed using composition rather than inheritance. For instance, you can define a smart pointer wrapper which will perform reference counting on objects of any type:

```
template <class T>
struct refcounted
{
  refcounted(T* object) : _object(object), _count(0) {}

  T* operator->() { return _object; }
  operator T*() { return _object; }

  void retain() { ++_count; }

  void release()
  {
    if (--_count == 0) { delete _object; }
  }

  private:
    T* _object;
    int _count;
};
```

Then, instead of calling methods on the object itself, you'd be calling methods in its wrapper. This not only allows more generic programming: it also lets you separate concerns (since ideally, your object should be more concerned about what it should do, than how its memory should be managed in different situations).

Lastly, in a language that has both primitives and actual objects like C++, the benefits of having a base-class (a consistent interface for ***every*** value) are lost, since then you have certain values which cannot conform to that interface. In order to use primitives in that sort of a situation, you need to lift them into objects (if your compiler won't do it automatically). This creates a lot of complication.

So, the short answer to your question: C++ doesn't have a base-class because, having parametric polymorphism through templates, it doesn't need to.

Comment: It's OK! Glad you found it helpful :)

Comment: For point 3, I counter with C#. C# has primitives that _can_ be boxed to `object` (`System.Object`), but they don't need to be. To the compiler, `int` and `System.Int32` are aliases and can be used interchangeably; the runtime handles boxing when needed.

Comment: In C++, there's no need for boxing. With templates, the compiler generates the correct code at compile time.

Comment: Please note that while this (old) answer demonstrates a reference counted smart pointer, C++11 now has [`std::shared_ptr`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/shared_ptr/) which should be used instead.

Answer (score 18):

The dominant paradigm for C++ variables is pass-by-value, not pass-by-ref. Forcing everything to be derived from a root `Object` would make passing them by value an error ipse facto.

(Because accepting an Object by value as parameter, would by definition slice it and remove its soul).

This is unwelcome. C++ makes you think about whether you wanted value or reference semantics, giving you the choice. This is a big thing in performance computing.

Comment: It would not be an error on it's own. Type hierarchies already exist, and they utilize pass-by-value quite well when appropriate. However it would encourage more heap-based strategies where pass-by-reference is more appropriate.

Comment: IMHO, a good language should have distinct kinds of inheritance for the situations where a derived class can legitimately be used as a base-class object using slice-by-reference, those where it can be turned into one using slice-by-value, and those where neither is legitimate.  The value of having a common base type for things that can be sliced would be limited, but many things can't be sliced and must be stored indirectly; the additional cost of having such things derive from a common `Object` would be relatively slight.

Answer (score 4):

**The problem is that there IS such a type in C++!** It is `void`. :-) Any pointer may be safely implicitly cast to `void *`, including pointers to basic types, classes with no virtual table and classes with virtual table.

Since it should be compatible with all those categories of objects, `void` itself can not contain virtual methods. Without virtual functions and RTTI, no useful information on type can be obtained from `void` (it matches EVERY type, so can tell only things that are true for EVERY type), but virtual functions and RTTI would make simple types very ineffective and stop C++ from being a language suitable for low-level programming with direct memory access etc.

So, there is such type. It just provides very minimalistic (in fact, empty) interface due to low-level nature of the language. :-)

Comment: Pointer types and object types are not the same.  You cannot have an object of type `void`.

Comment: In fact, that's how inheritance in C++ usually works. One of the most important things it does is compatibility of pointer and reference types: where a pointer to a class is required, a pointer to a derived class may be given. And ability to static_cast pointers  between two types is a sign they are connected in a hierarchy. From this point of view, void definitely is a universal base class in C++.

Comment: If you declare a variable of type `void` it will not compile and you get [this error](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/91z5z198%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).  In Java you could have a variable of type `Object` and it would work.  That's the difference between `void` and a "real" type.  Perhaps it is true that `void` is the base type for everything, but as it does not provide any constructors, methods, or fields, there is no way to tell it is there or not.  This assertion cannot be proved or disproved.

Comment: In Java every variable is a reference. That's the difference. :-) (BTW, in C++ there also are abstract classes you can not use to declare a variable). And in my answer I explained why it is not possible to get RTTI from void. So, theoretically void still is a base class for everything. static_cast is a proof, since it performs casts only between related types, and it can be used for void. But you are right, absence of RTTI access in void really makes in very different from base types in the higher level languages.

Comment: `void` is a keyword which indicates the absence of a type or an unspecified type (in the case of a pointer type declaration).  It is not a type itself.  Just because you come up with a theory that sounds good in your head doesn't make it correct.

Comment: bcrist, totally disagree, have you read the answer? void behaves exactly as a universal base type when it comes to casting pointers. You cannot create instances, but that is similar to abstract classes. What else? sizeof()? Well, no sizeof(). The fact it provides no real functions is obvious and explained above. Any pointer can be cast to a similar pointer to void, so everything extends void. In terms of casting pointers that is a complete equivalent to "void is a universal base class".

Comment: And it is NOT just a keyword. It's a type.

Comment: @Ellioh After consulting the C++11 standard §3.9.1p9, I concede that `void` is a type (and discovered a somewhat clever [use of `? :`](http://ideone.com/c4xmAB)), but it's still a long way from being a universal base class.  For one thing, it is "an incomplete type which cannot be completed," and for another, there is no `void&` type.

Answer (score -4):

C++ was initially called "C with classes". 
It is a progression of the C language, unlike some other more modern things like C#.
And you can not see C++ as a language, but as a foundation of languages (Yes, I am remembering the Scott Meyers book Effective C++).

C itself is a mix of languages, the C programming language and its preprocessor.

C++ adds another mix:

- the class/objects approach
- templates
- the STL

I personally don't like some stuff that come directly from C to C++. One example is the enum feature. The way C# allows the developer to use it is way better: it limits the enum in its own scope, it has a Count property and it is easily iterable.

As C++ wanted to be retrocompatible with C, the designer was very permissive to allow the C language to enter in its whole to C++ (there are some subtle differences, but I do not remember any thing that you could do using a C compiler that you could not do using a C++ compiler).

Comment: "can not see C++ as a language, but as a foundation of languages"... care to actually explain and illustrate what that bizarre statement's driving at?  Multiple paradigms is distinct from "multiple languages", though it's fair to say the preprocessor is disjoint from the rest of the compiler steps - good point.  Re enums - they can trivially be wrapped in a class scope if desired, and the entire language lacks introspection - a major issue, though in this case it can be approximated - see Boost vault's benum code.  Is your point re Q only: C++ didn't *start* with a universal base?

Comment: @Tony: Curiously, the book I refered the only thing they don't even mention as another language is the preprocessor, which is the only one you considerate separately. I understand your point of view, as the preprocessor parses its own input first.
But, having a templating mechanism is like having another language that does the generalization for you. You apply a template syntax and you will have the compiler generating functions for every single type you have.
When you can have a program written in C and give its input to a C++ compiler, this is two languages in one: C and C with objects=>C++

Comment: STL, it can be seen as an add-on, but it has very practical classes and containers that through templates NATIVELY extend the power of C++.
And the enums I was saying are the NATIVE enums. When you speak of Boost, you are relying on third-party code that is not NATIVE to the language. In C#, I don't have to include anything extern for having an iterable and self-scoped enum.
In C++, a trick I often use, is to call the last item of a enum - without assigned values, so they are automatically started from zero and incremented - something like NUM_ITEMS, and this gives me the upper bound.

Comment: thanks for your further explanation - I can at least see where you're coming from; I have heard a few people complain that learning to use templates felt disjoint from other C++ programming although that's certainly not my experience.  I'll leave other readers to make what they will of the other perspectives you present.  Cheers.

Comment: I think the biggest problem with having a universal base type is that such a type would be useless if it didn't have any virtual methods; C++ didn't want to add any overhead for struct types that don't have any virtual methods, but every object of any type that has any virtual methods must have, at minimum, pointer to a dispatch table.  If classes and structures had inhabited different universes, it might have been possible to have a universal class object, but classes and structs are basically the same thing in C++.

Answer (score -4):

C++ is a strongly typed language.  Yet it is puzzling that it does not have a universal object type in the context of template specialization.

Take, for example, the pattern

```
template <class T> class Hook;
template <class ReturnType, class ... ArgTypes>
class Hook<ReturnType (ArgTypes...)>
{
   ...
   ReturnType operator () (ArgTypes... args) { ... }
};
```

which can be instantiated as

```
Hook<decltype(some_function)> ...;
```

Now let's assume that we want the same for a particular function.  Like

```
template <auto fallback> class Hook;
template <auto fallback, class ReturnType, class ... ArgTypes>
class Hook<ReturnType fallback(ArgTypes...)>
{
   ...
   ReturnType operator () (ArgTypes... args) { ... }
};
```

with the specialized instantiation

```
Hook<some_function> ...
```

But alas, even though class T can stand in for any type (class or not) before specialization, there is no equivalent `auto fallback` (I am using that syntax as the most obvious generic non-type one in this context) that could stand in for any non-type template argument before specialization.

So in general this pattern does not transfer from type template arguments to non-type template arguments.

Like with a lot of corners in the C++ language, the answer is likely "no committee member thought of it".

Comment: Even if (something like) your `ReturnType fallback(ArgTypes...)` would work, it would be bad design. `template <class T, auto fallback> class Hook; template <class ReturnType, class ... ArgTypes> class Hook<ReturnType (ArgTypes...), ReturnType(*fallback)(ArgTypes...)> ...` does what you want and means the template parameters of `Hook` are of consistent *kinds*