# access the own interface with the scope operator doesnt work?

Tags: c++, interface, polymorphism

While playing around with polymorphism and templates i eventually dug up a strange (at least for me) behaviour of the scope operator. When i tried to access a method of a **b**aseclass using the **i**nterface with the scope operator within a **d**erived class, i get a linker error. I can only assume that the scope operator doesnt look into the vtable and tries to run the method directly from the interface, which is actually pure virtual.

Here is the example for that:

```
struct i
{
    virtual void set(char* in, short len) = 0;
    virtual char* getStr() = 0;
    virtual ~i() {}
};

template <int size = 10>
struct b : public i // this one is like an char-Array
{
    char str[size];
    void set(char* in, short len) { memcpy(this->getStr(),in,len); }
    char* getStr() { return str;}
};

template <int size = 10>
struct d : public  b<size> // this one is like an cString
{
    void set(char* in) { strcpy(this->getStr(),in); }
};

struct final : public d<4>
{
    void test()
    {
        set("abc"); ///< Works
        d<4>::set("abc"); ///< Works
        //set("abc",3); ///< Error : no matching function for call to 'final::set(const char [4], int)' (its shadowed by d)
        //note: candidates are: void d<size>::set(char*) [with int size = 4]
        b<4>::set("abc",3); ///< Works
        //i::set("abc",3); ///< Linker Error:  (.gnu.linkonce.t._ZN5final4testEv+0x68) : Error : undefined reference to `i::set(char*, short)'
        //this->set("abc",3); ///< Error : no matching function for call to 'final::set(const char [4], int)' (its shadowed by d too)
        ((i*) this)->set("abc",3); ///< Works!
    }
};

int main()
{
  final f;
  f.test();
  return 0;
}
```

The background why i tried this, is to avoid changing the template parameter of every call to a templated base class, when i might change the size of the final class.

So can somebody explain me why this happens with the scope operator?

Funny is that it does work, when casting the "this" pointer to a interface pointer and then using the baseclass's method with that. Is this actually valid and practicable?

BTW: i use GCC 4.1.2

EDIT: 
Just to clarify, i know d::set is shadowing b::set .. thats not the problem, i am just asking about the linker error!

Comment: Before somebody starts explaining the concept of visibility and hiding, take a moment to ponder on the type of string literals, which converts to `const char *` rather than `char *`.

Comment: @avakar But there is an implicit conversion to `char*` if the `char const*` is the result of an array to pointer conversion of a string literal.  He certainly should be using `char const*` for his parameter types, but that has nothing to do with his question.

Comment: @JamesKanze, that's why I wrote a comment, rather than an answer.

Comment: Well i usually use const parameters. just forgot that within my test classes. But i never reallized that there is a implicit conversion for char* so far! **Cool**

Answer (score 0):

When you write `Base::symbol` in a class context, `symbol` will
always be resolved statically, with name lookup starting in the
class `Base`.  The reason is simple: that's the way you access
masked members in derived classes.  Otherwise, you'd be unable
to chain functions, e.g.:

```
void
Derived::function()
{
    Base::function();   //  calls the function in Base before doing anything else.
    //  ...
}
```

At the time C++ was being developed, this was felt to be
important, and even today, you'd want to support some way of
doing it.

One idea for working around this:

```
template <int size=10>
struct d : public b<size>
{
    typedef b<size> Base;
    // ...
};
```

Then in `final`, refer to `Base::set`.

Comment: okay cool workaround! have not though of that, but thats still not the answer to my question, why i get that linker error? or does the static lookup cause that, because its not looking into the vtable?

Comment: @PhilippMichalski The linker error is because there is no implementation of `i::set`.

Comment: So the operator:: circumvents the vTable and with using the operator-> i force the compiler/linker to watch into the vTable, as i did in my last line. This was kinda unexpected

Answer (score 0):

Oh i finally found the answer to my question by myself:

*Polymorphism needs a indirection!*

As stated here: [Polymorphic objects on the stack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5894775/polymorphic-objects-on-the-stack?rq=1)

Thanks for pointing THAT out ;)