# Alternatives to normal polymorphism in embedded?

Tags: c++, c++11, polymorphism, embedded

I've got a problem in my project for which polymorphism with heap allocation would be perfect. Unfortunately I'm not allowed to use any heap allocation. So I went on and implemented a way to have dynamic polymorphism on the stack. But as it turns out a simple test program which switched an led on and off used 7.1kb of flash just to create my custom vtables to copy the object correctly, this is way too much.

I've also tried out CTRP, but this wouldn't work either because I need to store the objects in a container.

What alternatives are there to normal C++ polymorphism, that don't require heap allocation and don't take up too much flash?

Comment: You have conflated two things - best to include some code to illustrate the dynamic memory allocation you wish to eliminate.   Polymorphism on its own does not require heap allocation as explained at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5894775/polymorphic-objects-on-the-stack.  There are however common patterns that use polymorphism and dynamic memory allocation Miro Samek's article at https://barrgroup.com/embedded-systems/how-to/polymorphism-no-heap-memory describes solutions for eliminating dynamic memory allocation in these cases.

Comment: You could perhaps allocate as much as possible on the stack at program startup and use a custom allocator with the standard containers.

Comment: The project may be misconfigured. Polymorphism isn't that costly. As it mentioned in the links @Clifford provided, *placement new* may be a good alternative.

Comment: Have you tried identical comdat folding, that makes two function pointers that have the same assembly share executable code?  This is available in various linkers.

Comment: Also, are your polymorphic classes guaranteed to be plain old data (like, trivial to copy and destroy), or must they support all C++ features?  That could reduce your vtable overhead.

Comment: Finally, note that **stack** based resources might solve your problems, and **stack** based dynamic allocation of polymorphic objects is easier than some alternatives.  It does significantly restrict your lifetime control.  You can also reduce the amount of copy operations you erase; support only move-construct (!) and destroy, dropping the amount of erasure from 5 to 2.  Then for trivially destructible and copyable types, reuse the same (partial) vtable and/or operations.  Also, split the concept of "views" from "values"; a view doesn't need to know how to destroy or copy/move.

Comment: "I'm not allowed to use any heap allocation." -- 1) have you been able to create code that 'works' the way you want it to despite using heap? (to understand what aspect of using heap is the problem)  2) Did you know that (in most implementations) std::string, std::vector, and many other c++ library items use heap?  3) and are you saying you do not use them?  4)  Could you state clearly why disallowing heap allocation is important to your effort.

Comment: Do not give up to soon on Polymorphism. We have been using it for years and your code size is really strange. We do get small code. I do not know what you have made around a led, we use it mainly around peripherals which send abstract messages later implemented. Also our state machines use it a lot.

Comment: The place of object/instance allocation has nothing to do with the place of vtable allocation. You need to post the actual code and compiler options, because it seems that you are doing something very strange and it isn't related to inheritance. Check your map file and spot the actual size of the vtable, and of other things. Note that a C++ CRT may contain tonnes of extra bloat if you use various other exotic features of the language.