# Is there any class in c++ which is superclass of all the classes?

Tags: c++

Like java `Java.lang.Object` is the super-class for all the classes so in C++ is there any class
like `Object`?

Comment: have you tried searching for an answer, actually? There are even [discussions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5697328/why-is-there-no-base-class-in-c) ready to be read on that topic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Standard native C++ does not have any such class, but the C++ .NET variant (just like other .NET languages like C#, VB.NET) does have it: it is conveniently called Object (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.aspx)

It is, however, a managed language, requiring .NET framework installed to run compiled programs. ( Like in Java)

Answer (score 23):

No, there is not. In C++ you pay for what you use, not more.

You can have `void*` that can point to anything, or write your own base class if that makes sense.

Answer (score 9):

No, C++ doesn't have that concept.